# adsense ads not showing on larger screens only

Tags: adsense

I have implemented 3 adsense ads on my amp-html page: 
[http://orandanow.com/オランダ移住.html](http://orandanow.com/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E7%A7%BB%E4%BD%8F.html)

The ads show on small screens, but not on large screens.  On large screens, I get the following error on the console:

```
    %E3%82%AA%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E7%A7%BB%E4%BD%8F.html:1 The resource https://d-26902707551711738596.ampproject.net/1522350285886/frame.html was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

    %E3%82%AA%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E7%A7%BB%E4%BD%8F.html:1 The resource https://3p.ampproject.net/1522350285886/f.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

    %E3%82%AA%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E7%A7%BB%E4%BD%8F.html:1 The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?